y-axis numbers not displaying in openpyxl graph output
Y-axis does not display in a graph I am outputting from openpyxl using a python script node in KNIME. Here is the code that creates and saves the graph.
                chart = LineChart()
                data = Reference(ws, min_col=start_column, max_col=end_column, min_row=start_row+8, max_row=end_row+6)
                categories = Reference(ws, min_col=start_column+1, max_col=end_column, min_row=start_row, max_row = start_row)
                chart.add_data(data, titles_from_data=True, from_rows=True)
                chart.set_categories(categories)
                # chart.switch_row_col = False
                out_cell_coord = "A" + str(cell.row + 2)
                chart.width = 13
                chart.height =6.1

                ws.add_chart(chart, out_cell_coord)

The chart also has rounded edges now and the legend overlaps onto the graph. Previously it was formatted nicely with automatic y-axis, x-axis, and legend that is on the side of the graph.
I have tried various parameters moving or setting the y-axis to no avail.
chart.y_axis.title = "Quantity"  # Set the y-axis title
chart.y_axis.numFmt = "0"  # Display numbers without decimal places

This causes the title to show up but still the numbers do not display
I also tried
chart.y_axis = NumericAxis()

This did nothing
I also tried
chart.y_axis.scaling.min = 0
chart.y_axis.scaling.max = 100

This cropped the graph to the appropriate size but still the numbers do not show up on the side of the graph.

"Previously it was formatted nicely..." Previous to what? i.e. what has changed between when the graph was properly formatted and now?

It is very specific to my software the python script is running in, but the only thing I changed was moving the KNIME workflow from my local drive to the data area workflow local drive. Which is still my local drive but it seems to have changed the default format of the graph. I was hoping I could override that change but didn't know how.

Can you try the complete example of Line Charts from openpyxl documenation? Are the results also not correct? If they are correct, what exactly are the code differences to your code? If they are not correct, then we have a Minimal, Reproducible Example now to talk about. Then please edit your question and provide that complete example and the results there.
